# Java generics method

Tags: java, class, generics, methods, return

First of all, I have not much experience with java generics.

I hava a method kind of that:

```
public static Set<Object> getObjects(Class<? extends Object> clazz) {
    if (clazz == null) {
        clazz = Object.class;
    }

    Set<Object> result = new HashSet<Object>();
    Object object;

    for (/*a loop*/) {
        object = /*get an object*/;

        if (clazz.isInstance(object)) {
            result.add(object);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And I thought it would be better to use generics, to get the right return type. So I changed the method to this:

```
public static <T> Set<T> getObjects(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz == null) {
        //what should I do instead? Throw exception?
    }

    Set<T> result = new HashSet<T>();
    Object object;

    for (/*a loop*/) {
        object = /*get an object*/;

        if (clazz.isInstance(object)) {//or should I use object instanceof T? If yes, I don't event use clazz. Would it be bad practice?
            result.add((T) object);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

My questions: See comments in second code. Should I use generics here? Do I use it right? How would you do it?

Comment: Can you just make the signature public static <T extends Object> Set<T> getObjects(Class<T> clazz)?

Comment: Where are you getting the objects from?

Comment: @PaulBoddington from an api for a yaml configuration but that's not important, as it's only a similar example method that I really use. The first method without generics works fine for me but I thought it would be better with generics because I always had to cast the result.

Comment: So the actual question is: Is it bad practice to pass a `Class` type to a method just for generics.

Comment: You have to pass a class object because `instanceof T` doesn't compile.

Comment: Adding a parameter of type Class<T> is very common with Java generics. Due to type erasure it's unavoidable.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I know, but it would be also possible to pass an instance of the type, instead of the class. So is it common to pass the class?

Comment: Yes. Using an instance just to call `getClass` on it is not good practice. Sometimes the result of `getClass` can be surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, yes, you should probably throw an IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException if null is passed as the method argument.

Also, this line

```
result.add((T) object);
```

should probably use clazz to do the cast. Because the T is erased you don't get any safety from the casting and BadThings(tm) can happen. So, it should really look like

```
result.add(clazz.cast(object));
```

Also, if you're using Java8 then you might like to consider using the streams API. Assuming there's some method you can call which returns a collection of 'all' the objects, then your method would look like

```
 public static <T> Set<T> getObjects(Class<T> clazz) {
      if (clazz == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      return getAllTheObjects().stream()
                               .filter(clazz::isInstance)
                               .map(clazz::cast)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
 }
```

Comment: result.add((T) object)

is fine since it's already within the clazz.isInstance(object) check. Therefore, it should be keep as is and the Unsafe cast compiler warning can be suppressed.

        result.add(clazz.cast(object));

will introduce run time overhead.

Comment: The runtime overhead of clazz.cast is really quite minimal, and the implementation of the cast() method is just a null check followed by a cast to T. I'd be surprised if any real world application had a demonstrable problem as a result of calling clazz.cast over a straight cast. Most likely the jvm would inline the code and optimise out the null check anyway. Suppressing warnings is generally a bad habit to get into even if it's alright 'this time'. Subsequent code changes can invalidate that reasoning and subtle bugs can creep in.